# App installed from Play Store freezees

Tags: android, google-play, conversion-tracking

When I open app installed the from Google Play Store it freezes forever.
I don't have that problem when I install signed app using console (adb).

In my app logs I've found infinitive loop of logs:

```
06-30 11:15:47.553 31306-31306/? I/GoogleConversionReporter: Received install referrer: utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic
06-30 11:15:47.532 31306-31306/? I/GoogleConversionReporter: Registering: http://hostname/?referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle-play%26utm_medium%3Dorganic
06-30 11:15:47.532 31306-31306/? W/GoogleConversionReporter: Failed to parse referrer from: http://hostname/?referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle-play%26utm_medium%3Dorganic
```

Apps:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.domodi
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.homebook

Comment: did you uncheck build automatically before signing your apk..?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found reason.

We use some Install Referrer Broadcast Receivers in one class, one of them **Apsalar** according to it's [documentation](http://support.apsalar.com/customer/portal/articles/717507-integrating-the-android-sdk) have to be in separated class and that receiver have to be declared at first in the Manifest.xml (sick design).

My Manifest look like this:

```
    <!-- Apsalar receiver must be declareted above the rest Install Referrer Receivers !!! -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.apsalar.sdk.ApsalarReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Custom receiver to dispatch INSTALL_REFERRER intent-->
    <receiver
        android:name=".InstallReferrerDispatcherReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```